# How is a Ufer ground attached to the panel?

Tags: electrical, grounding, grounding-and-bonding

I am planning a addition to my house. I'm not sure of the current state of the house's grounding system (built in the 1890s, last updated in the early 1970's by my estimation, so "minimal" and "not to current code" is a safe assumption), so it makes sense to plan for a Ufer ground in the new foundation. I'll plan on attaching this to the new meter/main panel that will then feed to the existing (currently main, to be converted to sub) panel and to a new sub panel.

I would presume that some sort of copper grounding rod is to stick out of the top of the footing and continue up through the block wall and stick up above the top of the wall, then the grounding wire from the meter/main will attach to this with a grounding clamp, probably on the outside to allow for easier inspection (now and in the future).

- Currently my state is on NEC 2008.
- I believe I have a 200A service, to be confirmed with the PoCo soon.

1. What are the applicable code section(s) that apply to this so I can prepare for my inspection?

   - Are there requirements/allowances in newer code revisions that are applicable that would make I could quote the additional safety and allow for "retrofit" (to older code)?
2. How is the Ufer ground to be physically/electrically connected to the meter/main?

Comment: The common method seems to be a rebar sticking up, with a grounding wire clamped to it. I swear someone posted a picture of the inspection hatch (in the drywall above the concrete) they had for that connection on their ground on here someplace, which I can't find at the moment.

Comment: There was a question about an inspection hatch. I read through it, but it was more focused on the hatch itself, not so much the actual connection methodology. Maybe I missed an important detail as I skimmed.

Comment: There's some language in code (as one option) that never seems to actually be done involving copper wire and connectors listed for concrete encasement, but the practical economy of the other option of stub up heavy enough rebar and tie it all properly (I see no reason to limit oneself to the minimum required 20 ft) and connect above the concrete generally wins in practice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will connect a bit of rebar to the reinforcement of your foundation and leave it sticking out of the concrete, that will be your ground connection.

Internal to the concrete you will need larger than 1/2 inch rebar which is tied together for the entire portion that you want to serve as the electrode (at least 20 feet). The concrete itself must be resting on bare soil.

You will want 2 of those rebar sticking out on opposite ends of the foundation so you can check whether there is electrical continuity of rebar inside the concrete for length you want to use as grounding electrode.

The connection will be a grounding clamp with a normal green or bare aluminum or copper wire of adequate gauge to the panel. The clamp itself must be accessible for service.

If you are pulling a permit you should be able to ask the inspector for more details and personal preferences they have for them.

Comment: And make sure that no other contractor comes along and cuts off the rebar extending out of the foundation.  In a wood frame structure the bottom plate has to be drilled so the ground connections end up inside the wall.  (A tip from the electrician who wired our house and has seen it happen)

Comment: Also, even though it may seem over-kill, the connections of the ground wires to the rebar must be permanently accessible.